# How to compute the number of combinations with [1, N] that makes the combination sum equals to N?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

```
when n = 1
S(1) = 1;

when n = 2, there are two combinations
2 = 2
2 = 1 + 1
S(2) = 2;

when n = 3, there are 3
3 = 3
3 = 1 + 1 + 1
3 = 1 + 2
S(3) = 3

4 = 4
4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1
4 = 2 + 1 + 1
4 = 2 + 2
4 = 3 + 1
S(4) = 5

…………
```

With n <= 1000, how to compute S(n)? I came out with a brute-force dfs solution, here is the code in python:

```
class S1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.cnt = 1

    def dfs(self, begin, n, remain):
        if n == 1: return
        if remain == 0:
            self.cnt += 1
            return 
        if remain < 0:
            return 
        for i in range(begin, n):
            self.dfs(i, n, remain - i)
```

Is there some other ways not using recursion and have smaller time complexity to do this?

Comment: What maximum size `n` are you considering?

Comment: @Damien, n is less than 1000

Comment: I'd look at [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution consists in defining a function `f(s, d)`, corresponding to the number of combinations of sum `s`, with a maximum digit equal to or less than `d`.

Then, we can use the recursive relationship

```
f(s, d) = f(s, d-1) + f(s-d, d)
```

The first term `f(s, d-1)` corresponds to combinations with all terms less or equal to `d-1`, and the second term `f(s-d, d)` corresponds to the case where at least one element is equal to `d`.

One must take care of some special values:

```
 f(s, 1) = 1
 if (d > s) then f(s, d) = f(s, s)
 f(0,d) = 1
```

This can be implemented in an iterative way. This can be implemented equivalently in a recursive way. However, in the later case, it is important to use memorization in order to avoid calculating the same value several times.

The final answer is equal to

```
 S(n) = f(n, n)
```

The total complexity is O(n^2), which should be enough for a maximum size `n = 1000`.

---

What follows is an implementation in C++ to illustrate the algorithm. For `n = 1000` for example, the solution is provided in about 10 ms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::string toString(__int128 num) {
    auto neg = num < 0;
    if (neg) num = -num;
    std::string str;
    do {
        int digit = num % 10;
        str += std::to_string(digit);
        num /= 10;
    } while (num != 0);
    std::string rev;
    if (neg) rev = "-" + std::string (str.rbegin(), str.rend());
    else rev = std::string (str.rbegin(), str.rend());
    return rev;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "enter n: ";
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::vector<std::vector<__int128>> sums (n+1, std::vector<__int128> (n+1));
    
    for (int d = 0; d <= n; d++) {
        sums[0][d] = 1;
    }
    for (int sum = 1; sum <= n; sum++) {
        sums[sum][1] = 1;
        for (int d = 2; d <= sum; d++) {
            int dp = std::min (sum-d, d);
            sums[sum][d] = sums[sum][d-1] + sums[sum-d][dp];
        }
    }
    std::cout << "S[" << n << "]= " << toString(sums[n][n]) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is clearly incorrect: the maximum digit does not need to be `n`.

Comment: @stf The formulas doesn't imply that the maximum digit need to be `n`, but that the maximum allowed digit is `n`. I tested the formulas on different use cases. Could you provide an example (a value of  `n`) for which these formulas will provide a wrong result?

Comment: I was referring to your first paragraph and your last equation.

Comment: @stf OK, I understand, the text was ambiguous. I modified it. Note that I implemented it in C++ (I don't know Python).  Results seem correct. For n=1000, result obtained in about 10ms.  In my opinion, the code doesn't add real values in addition to the algorithm description.

Comment: Hi @Damien, cloud you attach your c++ code (iterative) in the answer? With the code posted, maybe I can understand the logic more easily.

Comment: @YQ.Wang I have added the code. i also tried to add more explanations in the text.